# I want to color the result of a search

Tags: swift3

I want to color the result of a search

[image]

Comment: This question is too generic, what is it that you need help with? How have you implemented the display of the text passage? This needs further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSAttributedString and give the words you want to color a foreground color attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this logic gets you well....

You can store all the text in and **array** of words separating them by the "**space**" and the use the **compare function** in swift and then perform task according to that so that you can change the colour of that particular word.

I hope this logic can be helpful. if you need any more clarification let me know cheers :)